# Использовние strand

Tags: c++, boost, asio

До недавнего времени я использовал boost-1.69, но вот увидел, что по дефолту на моей ос уже доступен пакет поновее: 1.71 - и решил обновиться. И тут возникла проблема: у меня есть некоторый асинхронный многопоточный сервак работающий по принципу запрос-ответ и для избежания возможной конкуренции я использовал `strand`-ы, которые лежали рядом с сокетами и биндились при асинхронном чтении и/или записи. Но в 1.71, как я вижу, принцип работы со `strand` изменился, а с ними и сами сокеты (что стало для меня некоторой неожиданностью). Теперь сокет имеет не 1 шаблонный параметр как раньше, а 2, новый - `Executor`. И теперь сокет в конструкторе может принимать вместо `io_context` (как раньше) `strand`, а учитывая то, что у него есть метод `get_executor`, то правильно ли я понимаю, что он сейчас возвращает `strand` а не `io_context` как раньше?

Также я сравнивал примеры в документации по asio и, если раньше обекты `strand` использовались явно, то сейчас они лишь используются в качестве аргумента к сокету, а то и вообще убраны из примера. Правильно ли я понимаю, что теперь `strand` будет использоваться неявно, даже если в `async_*` мы не использовали `bind_executor`?

Comment: По-моему там раньше возвращался `service_type`, а сейчас `executor_type`. *"а то и вообще убраны из примера"* - из какого примера?